# Android - Youtube Data Api - Get user permission without having to catch GoogleAuthIOException

Tags: android, google-authentication, youtube-data-api

I want to use the Youtube Data API.So i show an Account Picker dialog, get an email id, and then i want to access account-specific data from the user's Youtube account.

According to the docs, it seems that the first time any API call is made, `GoogleAuthIOException` will be thrown,and then you have to catch it, and get permission from the user.

However, is there a way to trigger the permission dialog without having to catch`GoogleAuthIOException` ? Like, can my app ask for permission just after i get the email id from the picker?